# How to verify the acknowledgement logic in google play in app purchase?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, android-inapp-purchase

Per [doc](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#process)

> Once you've verified the purchase, your app is ready to grant entitlement to the user. After granting entitlement, your app must then acknowledge the purchase. This acknowledgement communicates to Google Play that you have granted entitlement for the purchase.

> Note: **If you do not acknowledge a purchase within three days, the user automatically receives a refund**, and Google Play revokes the purchase.

We know after Google Play Billing Library 3.0, we must acknowledge the purchase within 3 days. Otherwise, the purchase will be automatically refunded by google play.

The acknowledge logic is done on our server-side, we want to double-check the acknowledge logic through fetching the refunded purchase due to the acknowledgment issue. For example, our server does acknowledge one purchase successfully. Does the refund of this purchase still happen? One solution is to retrieve the refunded purchase data from google play and check whether the acknowledgment is done on our server-side.

However, per google play support guys, we could Not fetch those refunded purchases due to the acknowledgement issues through [Voided Purchase](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/voided-purchases).

Is there any way to verify the acknowledgement logic in google play in-app purchase? Or anything am I missing?

Comment: Can't you just check the `acknowledgementState` property? (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions)

Comment: Only when acknowledgementState is 0, our server could send an acknowledgement for this purchase.

Comment: @romainsalles, furthermore, we want to check if there is one purchase is acknowledged successfully, unfortunately, googleplay do the refunded to this purchase...

Comment: To check if a purchase has been acknowledged, request it on the GET API (https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.subscriptions/get) and check its `acknowledgementState`.

Comment: @romainsalles, you are right, the same logic to check acknowledgementState is done on our server